# 127.0.0.1 refused to connect in docker django

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect to an instance of django running in docker.  As far as i can tell I've opened the correct port, and see in docker ps that there is tcp on port 8000, but it there is no forwarding to the port.

After reading the docker compose docs on ports, i would expect this to work (I can view pgadmin on 127.0.0.1:9000 too).

My docker compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgresql:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: pguser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pgpassword
      POSTGRES_DB: pgdb

  pgadmin:
    restart: always
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
      GUNICORN_THREADS: 4
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 9000
    volumes:
      - ./utility/pgadmin4-servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json 
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: pgdb
      POSTGRES_USER: pguser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pgpassword
      POSTGRES_HOST: postgresql
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8000:8000"
      - "5555:5555"
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
      - pgadmin
```

I have tried with the following combinations for (app) `ports`, as are suggested [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports):

```
app:
  ...
  ports:
    - "8000"
    - "8000:8000"
    - "127.0.0.1:8000:8000"
```

but i still see `This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.` on trying to access the site.

I'm sure that this is a port forwarding problem, and that my server is turning correctly in django because i can run a docker attach to the container and curl a url with the expected response.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the fragment of your application that listens on the port (8000? 5555?)?

Comment: how are you running your django application inside docker? Also you need to check the logs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was running my application using the command:

```
docker-compose run app python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

With docker-compose you need to use the argument `--service-ports` to:

> Run command with the service's ports enabled and mapped to the host.

Thus my final command looked like this:

```
docker-compose run --service-ports app python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Documentation on `run` can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are running docker inside a virtual machine then you need to access your application through the  virtual machine IP address and *not using localhost or 127.0.0.1*. Try to get the virtual machine IP. Also please specify in which platform/environment you installed and running the docker.